# Error while installing nodeshark

Tags: node.js, npm, wireshark

Hello I am install nodeshark from [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodeshark), but I have and error:

```
    ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Documents$ sudo npm install nodeshark -g
    (node:8720) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.

    > nodeshark@0.0.5 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodeshark
    > node mnm.js build

    ERROR: Could not find "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include" check GLIB_CONFIG_INCLUDE_DIR environment variable.
    npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-22-generic
    npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "nodeshark" "-g"
    npm ERR! node v6.2.0
    npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

    npm ERR! nodeshark@0.0.5 install: `node mnm.js build`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the nodeshark@0.0.5 install script 'node mnm.js build'.
    npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the nodeshark package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     node mnm.js build
    npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    npm ERR!     npm bugs nodeshark
    npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls nodeshark
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Documents/npm-debug.log
```

I have tried to install build-deb wireshark, but still don't work. 
It seems that I need i386 for it to work, but I have this :

```
Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-22-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 12 22:03:46 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Can someone explain how I can solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it cant locate or dosent have the glib on line

```
ERROR: Could not find "/usr/lib/i386-     linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
```

You should make sure that file is available at the path specified or add the path to this file in the environment variables

if you haven't installed it previously

```
sudo apt-get install libperl-dev

sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

Another possibility is that it is incompatible with 64 bit systems, If this is true and also possible you can run it in a 32 bit vm (probably the best solution if you don't intend to reinstall a 32 bit distribution)

It is looking for a 32 bit library but you are running a 64 bit version of linux 
you could try changing the library path to your version of this library

It appears that mnm is required to run this software if you haven't already installed it run

```
npm install mnm
```